# settingwithcopywarning Pandas while using .remove() method to my data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

so, I am just trying to replace all nan values in my data frame with the mean of the column values and I have used the `.remove()` function and there it pops the error

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  return super().replace(
```

I have gone through the internet and found that we can use the `iloc` method or `loc` and I don't understand how to use it in this case where the values are being modified in a function.

here is the code I wrote

```
avghorse=df[["horsepower"]].astype(float).mean(axis=0)
df[["horsepower"]].replace(np.NaN,avghorse,inplace=True)
```

avghorse is the average of the column.
the column's datatype is float.

and,
I have converted the coulms datatype to float and its still showing me that its a object when I used the `df[["horsepower"]].astype(float)` line.

I am using jupyterlab and python 3.9.5

Comment: what is the command that creates `df`, or all the lines. The problem is more at one of these lines I think

Comment: other_path = "https://cf-courses-data.s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/IBMDeveloperSkillsNetwork-DA0101EN-SkillsNetwork/labs/Data%20files/auto.csv"
df=pd.read_csv(other_path,header=None)

Comment: headers = ["symboling","normalized-losses","make","fuel-type","aspiration", "num-of-doors","body-style",
         "drive-wheels","engine-location","wheel-base", "length","width","height","curb-weight","engine-type",
         "num-of-cylinders", "engine-size","fuel-system","bore","stroke","compression-ratio","horsepower",
         "peak-rpm","city-mpg","highway-mpg","price"]
df.columns=headers